# MySQL 5.5 + .NET Connector + Entity Framework + Migrations = FormatException

Tags: mysql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I tried to find a solution for my problem but my efforts until now was in vain. :-(

I created a web project using Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4, C#, Entity Framework 5.0, MySQL 5.5 and it's corresponding .NET connector (version 6.5.4). I'm using the code first approach for the entities and O/R mapping.

The problem I'm faced with is that I'm unable to execute what seemed to be a simple migration. Here are my entity classes:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    //[Timestamp]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Versao { get; set; }
}

public class Perfil
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    //[Timestamp]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Versao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permissao> Permissoes { get; set; }
}

public class Permissao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    //[Timestamp]
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Versao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Perfil> Perfis { get; set; }
}
```

The code generated by `Add-Migration Acesso` (only `Up()` method):

```
public partial class Acesso : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Usuario",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    NomeCompleto = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Email = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Login = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Senha = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Ativo = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Versao = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Perfil",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Nome = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Descricao = c.String(storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Versao = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Permissao",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Nome = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Descricao = c.String(storeType: "mediumtext"),
                    Versao = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.PerfilPermissao",
            c => new
                {
                    PerfilId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PermissaoId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.PerfilId, t.PermissaoId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Perfil", t => t.PerfilId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Permissao", t => t.PermissaoId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.PerfilId)
            .Index(t => t.PermissaoId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UsuarioPerfil",
            c => new
                {
                    UsuarioId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PerfilId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UsuarioId, t.PerfilId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Usuario", t => t.UsuarioId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Perfil", t => t.PerfilId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UsuarioId)
            .Index(t => t.PerfilId);

    }
}
```

First of all I had to change the properties named Versao (version) from

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Versao { get; set; }
```

to

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public int Versao { get; set; }
```

because an error ocurred before the change (something about the type rowversion not been qualified with a namespace or alias). After this change I was able to generate the migration but the `Update-Database` command failed with the following error shown in the console:

```
System.FormatException: Cadeia de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto.
    em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
```

(Input string was not in not in a correct format.)

I tried to use MySQL versions 5.5 and 5.1; the versions 6.5.4, 6.4.5 and 6.3.9 of the connector and couldn't solve the problem.

Is it possible to use MySQL, Entity Framework and code first approach? If not, what are the consequences of switching to ODBC connector instead of the .NET one?

Thanks in advance and sorry about the big question.

Comment: What's the stack trace? I wonder if this not this: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also try [.NET Connector 6.6](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_connector_net_6_62) because it is the first release claiming support for EF 4.3 (the first release with migrations). If it doesn't help you should try [dotConnect for MySql](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) (at least trial) to find if the problem is in .NET Connector or in EF. ODBC connector will not work with EF.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there... Unfortunately the .NET Connector 6.6 depends on the EntityFramework.dll Version=4.3.1.0 but Entity Framework 5.0 DLL's version is 4.4.0.0. A System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException happens when I try to run the migrations using the newer connector: System.IO.FileLoadException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 22):

I've [created a fork](https://bitbucket.org/kirk/mysql-data-connector-net-ef5/downloads/mysql-data-connector-net-ef5-2.zip) of MySQL Data Connector v.6.6.4 that supports the latest version of Entity Framework (v.5).

To use it, you can just [download the binaries](https://bitbucket.org/kirk/mysql-data-connector-net-ef5/downloads/mysql-data-connector-net-ef5.zip), which are replacement assemblies for `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity`.  Also make sure your project is dependent on EF5 rather than 4.3.

After you `Enable-Migrations` the first time, modify your `Configuration` class' constructor to include the line:

```
SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
```

At this point, you should be able to run `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` without issues.

The key  changes of my fork are as follows:

- The binaries are dependent on EF5 rather than EF4.3.
- EF5 prepends `dbo.` to all of your table names, which MySQL cannot handle.  Thus, my version hacks the SQL migration generator to strip out the `dbo.` prefix from the table names.  This all assumes you are not overriding the schema via the `TableAttribute` on the entity classes.
- It removes the usage of `CreatedOn` as Jimi mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Thanks for your fork. It got me moving. Where did you get the.NET/Connector source code to fork? I've been trying to find it to fix another problem (Unicode support) to no avail.

Comment: @sergiopereira, it comes with the [zip archive](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=412150).

Comment: Kirk, but where did you get it from? For now I just forked you repo on Bitbucket but it would be nice to know where the original source is if I need to fork again on a new version of it.

Comment: @sergiopereira, I thought I answered your question?  The source code is contained in the zip file I linked to in my previous comment.  (it comes with the connector) That's where I got the source code.  (I don't think it's available on github/bitbucket/etc., though I could be wrong)

Comment: D'oh. I thought your link pointed to the same zip from your fork. Thanks. I believe the source used to live on Launchpad but I could not find it there anymore.

Comment: Hi @KirkWoll I came across your answer and it's clarified a few things. One thing I was wondering is where does the code consider this: "This all assumes you are not overriding the schema via the TableAttribute on the entity classes" Since I am using that TableAttribute I'm getting problems and the inner TrimSchemaPrefix method is skipped on code generation. Any ideas?

Comment: @KirkWoll, I welcome an answer if you have one, in the meantime, to trick the system, I just used this convention for my Entity DTOs. [Table("dbo.User")] for UserDto and its worked ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Code Migration  is supported by .Net Connector 6.6 . I tried it already, the error you will get, when you run 'Update-Database'
No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.
dotConnect for MySql might work as they say they have added the migration support

Comment: A MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator exists in the MySql.Data.Entity package. You have to register it manually using SetMigrationSqlGenerator(). You also need to compile the .Net Connector 6.6 against .NET Framework 4.5 or you will experience what matheus.emm did above

Answer (score 2):

There are some useful how to guides about using EF+Connector/Net+EFMigrations.. I think it would help if you check them. The latest version of Connector/Net (6.6.4) depends on EF 4.3.1 The Connector/Net version supporting EF 5 is still in code stage.

[HowTo using EF Migrations and Connector/Net](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/entity_framework_4_3_1)

[Upgrading to Code Based Migrations EF 4.3.1 with Connector/Net 6.6](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/upgrading_to_code_first_migrations)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting below mentioned error

No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.

and got fixed with this statement

```
SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new ySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
```

T[image]his needs to be set under Configuration constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with using EF CTP5 (a.k.a version 4.4.0) is that CreatedOn method has been deprecated (which used to create the related table in the DB) and Connector/Net 6.6 is trying to migrate that table causing an exception.