# EF5 Database Migration with MySql

Tags: mysql

I encountered the below error when executing Enable-Migrations command against a MySql database:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName CodeFirstEFMySqlA1.Models.DataContext
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
   at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String namespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.ScaffoldInitialCreate()
   at   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.InitialCreateScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
```

The project was created using:
 - ASP.NET MVC4
 - EF5 Code First
 - MySql Database Server
 - MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity
 - A custom database initializer was implemented using System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer for creating migration history table.

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Rank { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

After executing the command "Enable-Migrations" the Configuration.cs class was generated but no migration classes were generated. The same error "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string" is raised if I try to execute "Add-Migration" command.

My attempt is to test how well EF5 Code First and Database Migration capabilities could be used against a MySql database server. As I see database creation can be done using a custom database initializer, however I could not get database migrations working.

Any thoughts on this problem are highly appreciated
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kirk Woll, I was able to find a solution for the above problem.

I used MySQL Data Connector v.6.6.4 and it has built in support for EF 5. Now Database Migrations works without a problem with MySql. Just to note I had to delete the previous database and let EF create a new one with Update-Database command.

Reference: [MySQL 5.5 + .NET Connector + Entity Framework + Migrations = FormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380147/mysql-5-5-net-connector-entity-framework-migrations-formatexception)